# Why is a DataViewManager not sorting?

Tags: .net, vb.net, ado.net, dataviewmanager

First off, a quick rundown of what the code is doing. I have two tables: Companies and Clients. There is a one to many relationship between Companies and Clients (one company can have many clients).

In some processing logic, I have both tables loaded into a DataSet - each are DataTables. I have added a DataRelation to set the relationship, and it works when I use GetChildRows on  a record from the Companies table.

However, I need to sort the records returned. After googling around some it looks like the DataViewManager is the way to go, and I have examined several basic examples. However, I cannot get my rows sorted. Am I missing something, or am I not using this how it is supposed to be used? Example code:

```
Dim ldvmManager As New DataViewManager(mdsData)
ldvmManager.DataViewSettings("Companies").Sort = "comName ASC"
ldvmManager.DataViewSettings("Clients").ApplyDefaultSort = False
ldvmManager.DataViewSettings("Clients").Sort = "entLastName ASC, entFirstName ASC"

For Each mdrCurrentCompany in ldvmManager.DataViewSettings("Companies").Table.Rows
    Dim ldrClients() as DataRow = mdrCurrentCompany.GetChildRows("CompaniesClients")
Next
```

No matter what I do, the first Client returned has a last name that starts with a 'B' and the second has one that starts with a 'A'. From there, the order is all mixed up. If I use my entire data instead of the subset I was using to test with, the first Client returned has a last name that starts with 'J'. It seems like it is still using whatever default sort was being used before I tried to use the DataViewManager.

Any ideas?

Comment: I just went ahead and used a DataTable.Select to get the filter and sort. I am still curious what the proper method is when using the DataViewManager - or does this only apply to using DataViews?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should be using DataView to get a sorted view of the DataTable.

Looking at the MSDN doc, it seems that DataViewManager stores the default settings (as that of DataTable, when created).

Someone who has worked with this can shed a light on this.